# Mosquitto_sub Error: Connection refused

Tags: debian, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using the Mosquitto(1.4.9) MQTT-Broker (version 3.1) on my Debian 7.8.

I try to execute this command:

```
mosquitto_sub -t "#" -v
```

The response:

```
Error: Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you sure that the broker is actually running on the machine? Have you started it?

Answer (score 2):

You need a broker.

To subscribe, try sending something like to this test server ..

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t "hello/world" -v
```

Then to publish the message send something like ..

```
mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t "hello/world" -m "Who's there"
```